# Dynamic import expression not working in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

Dynamic import expression not working in angular 8. I am trying to import and call function as below

```
//Working
//import('../../../../modules/supplier/service/supplier.service').then(m => {

//Not Working
const path: string = '../../../../modules/supplier/service/supplier.service';
import(path).then(m => {
    alert(m.TestFunction('Some Value'));
})
```

When I directly specify path like this `import('xxxx')` it works and able to access `TestFunction`. But when I put exact same path in `path` variable and use `import(path)` it's not working. I am not able to figure out what's going wrong here. Any suggestion will be helpful.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do it that way?

Comment: Thanks to reply @EvaldasBuinauskas. Actually I want to dynamically pass path to Import() based on condition.